# Потокобезопасный singleton

Tags: java

Вот потокобезопасный `singleton`:

```
public class Singleton {
    private volatile static Singleton instance;
    private Singleton() {}
    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            synchronized (Singleton.class) {
               if (instance == null) {
                   instance = new Singleton();
               }
            }
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Никак не пойму зачем ему `volatile`, если он и так лочится по `Singleton.class`. От чего это спасает ?

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1271/%D0%9A%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE-volatile-%D0%B2-java

Comment: @arkadij_ok я знаю, что такое `volatile` и даже знаю про кэш процессора. Вопрос в том, зачем нам делать `instance` защищенным от кеширования, если вторая проверка происходит внутри залоченного монитора ?

Comment: Не знал что можно синхронизировать по Object.class

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Операция создания объекта в Java не является атомарной.

Рассмотрим (*один из возможных*) пример с выполнением операции создания объекта и двумя потоками:

`Поток A` входит в метод `getInstance()`, в этот момент времени `instance == null` и он входит в синхронизированный блок, в котором тоже `instance == null` и начинает создание объекта `Singleton`. Сначала выделяется память под объект, потом этот объект инициализируется ссылкой на выделенную область памяти. В этот момент времени `Поток B` заходит в метод `getInstance()` видит, что `instance != null` и начинает использовать уже существующий, но еще не донца сконструированный объект (так как его поля еще не инициализированы).

Объявление поля `instance` как `volatile` (**JDK 5+**) устанавливает отношение *happens before* между инициализацией объекта `instance` `Потоком A` и возвратом объекта `instance` `Потоку B`.

Иными словами, объявление поля `instance` как `volatile` гарантирует, что `поток В` прочитает уже *полностью сконструированный* объект `instance`.

**UPD.** Из комментариев [@Roman](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/590975/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-singleton/591001?noredirect=1#comment793600_591001) еще одна причина необходимости использования `volatile`:

> Без `volatile` есть ещё одна проблема: если первая проверка `if (instance == null)` увидит не `null`, последующий `return instance` может увидеть `null`, в результате метод вернёт `null`.
>
> Если нет корректной синхронизации, то чтение, которое идёт "позже" может увидеть значение, которое было "раньше", т.к. JMM не запрещает переупорядочивать такие чтения.

Переменная, объявленная `volatile`, никогда не кешируется в память потока, то есть она в любой момент времени в любом потоке будет иметь одинаковое (*актуальное*) значение (если один поток меняет ее значение, то это значение сразу же доступно в других потоках).

Comment: Без `volatile` есть ещё одна проблема: если первая проверка `if (instance == null)` увидит не `null`, последующий `return instance` _может_ увидеть `null`, в результате метод вернёт `null`.

Comment: @Roman, А как в данной реализации можно обнулить `instance`?

Comment: Никто и не обнуляет `instance`. Просто если нет корректной синхронизации, то чтение, которое идёт "позже" может увидеть значение, которое было "раньше", т.к. JMM не запрещает переупорядочивать такие чтения. См. [простой пример](https://shipilev.net/blog/2016/close-encounters-of-jmm-kind/#wishful-hb-actual) и [пример из вопроса](https://shipilev.net/blog/2014/safe-public-construction/#_arm) (Unsafe DCL + Safe Singleton).

Comment: @Roman, Спасибо, добавил в ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Потому что чтение при сравнении

```
if (instance == null) {
```

происходит вне synchronized блока, а так уже и sideeffects могут быть, например, созданный объект в heap, но с ещё не вызванным конструктором или кешированное значение null. Модель памяти JDK 5.0 и выше требует этого, чтобы поведение многопоточных программ было предсказуемым.

Comment: сравнение происходит дважды