# Непонятный вывод при выполнении java программы

Tags: java, многопоточность, вывод

Написал код для изучения синхронной работы потоков(в этом случае не совсем синхронной, но не суть). Класс, в котором реализуются синх. методы:

```
class Element{
    int element;
    Element(int n){
        element = n;
    }
    synchronized int adding(){
        element+=1;
        return element;
    }
    synchronized int subtraction(){
        element-=1;
        return element;
    }
}
```

Работа первого потока:

```
public void run(){
    while (true){
        System.out.println(element.adding());
    }
}
```

Работа второго потока:

```
public void run(){
    while (true){
        System.out.println(element.subtraction());
    }
}
```

До некоторого момента вывод был понятен - целые числа с разницей в 1, пока там не появилось:

```
...
-474
-473
-472
-553
-472
-473
...
```

Что это?
upd. чисел с такой разницей достаточно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPD. Мой ответ не подходит. @nikialeksey верно написал, тут причина в неатоморности изменения числа и его вывода. Но я оставлю ответ, т.к. отсутствие volatile может приводить к похожей проблеме

Потоки в Java кэшируют данные, поэтому они могут быть неактуальными, нужно пометить `element` как [`volatile`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1271/%D0%9A%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE-volatile-%D0%B2-java), что позволяет видеть изменения сразу, `volatile int element;`. Стоит отметить, в данном случае это не замена `synchronized`, т.к. `element += 1;` не атомарная операция. Т.е. тут нужно использовать как `volatile` так и `synchronized`, но на самом деле было бы куда эффективней использовать [`AtomicInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html), чем синхронизацию. Данный класс гарантирует атомарность операций с объектом, а изменения будут видны сразу.

```
final AtomicInteger element = new AtomicInteger(n);

System.out.println(element.addAndGet(1)); // поток 1
System.out.println(element.addAndGet(-1)); // поток 2
```

Comment: Атомарные величины не помогут сделать вывод чисел, которые будут отличатся на 1, так как в коде каждого потока операция вывода и операция инкремента/декремента не синхронизированы.

Answer (score 1):

Имея такую синхронизацию, выводимые числа в консоль иногда не будут отличатся на 1. Рассмотрим ваш случай:

```
[thread-add] -474
[thread-add] -473
[thread-add] -472
[thread-sub] -553
[thread-sub] -472
[thread-sub] -473
```

То есть здесь видно, что в потоке вычитания выполнилось когда-то давно вычитание (получилось число -553) но не вывелось это число, затем поток вычитания уснул, передав выполнение другому потоку, и там началось выполнение сложения до -471 (**но это число не вывел**), после этого уснул поток сложения, передав выполнение потоку вычитания, который ранее уснул на выполнении операции вывода, и вывел -553, затем продолжил выполнение вычитания (-471 - 1 = -472). То есть в выражении:

```java
System.out.println(element.subtraction());
```

два атомарных действия: `element.subtraction()` и `System.out.println(...)`, поток может уснуть после выполнения любого из них. Чтобы все-таки был вывод чисел с разницей в единицу нужно сделать такую синхронизацию:

```java
public void run() {
    while (true) {
        synchronized (element) {
            int adding = element.adding();
            System.out.println(adding);
        }
    }
}
...
public void run() {
    while (true) {
        synchronized (element) {
            int subtraction = element.subtraction();
            System.out.println(subtraction);
        }
    }
}
```

То есть выполнение операций вычитания/сложения и вывода должны стать одной атомарной операцией.