# Если коллекцию пометить volatile можно ли сказать, что запись\удаление\чтение объектов будут выполняться в ней всегда атомарно?

Tags: java, многопоточность, volatile, атомарность

Предположим я создал коллекцию

```
volatile ArrayList <Integer> vo_al = new ArrayList<>();
```

**Вопрос:** Можно ли быть увереным, что когда я создам 100 потоков, которые будут читать и записывать туда значения, что потоки не попортят друг-другу память, а изменения которые внесёт один поток операцией

```
vo_al.add(2);
```

будут сразу видны всем другим потокам?

Есть ли в принципе смысл, в многопоточном программировании помечать коллекции словом **volatile?**

Comment: некоторые поля могу быть кешированы потоком в целях оптимизации. Например, вот будет у вас класс с полем `int myField` - возможна ситуация, что в одном потоке вы в него запишете новое значение, а после в другом птоке прочитаете старое значение, потому что другой поток поле закешировал. Чтобы такого не произошло, применяется ключепое слово `volatile`. Применение этого слова отменяет кеш потока, но не делает вашу структуру данных потокобезопасной.

Comment: `Есть ли в принципе смысл, в многопоточном программировании помечать коллекции словом volatile` если вы собираетесь читать эту коллекцию в разных потоках, то имеет смысл.

Comment: @tym32167 а запись почему не отработает атомарно?

Comment: [Ключевое слово volatile в Java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1271/%d0%9a%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be-volatile-%d0%b2-java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Конечно же нет. `volatile` никак не связан с объектом, который лежит по ссылке, он гарантирует, что запись и чтение переменной будет атомарно (насколько я знаю, не атомарными по записи и чтению являются только `long` и `double`) и что изменения переменной (изменение именно ссылки! а не какие-либо методы вроде `add`) будут сразу же видны другим потокам.

[Atomic Access](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html)

Если вам нужно безопасно изменять `List` в нескольких потоках, то используйте `Collections.synchronizedList`:

```
List<Integer> vo_al = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());
```

Но и это не означает, что не понадобится synchronized блок или другие методы синхронизации.
Например, нужно атомарно увеличить первый элемент списка на единицу. Даже с `synchronizedList` нужно использовать `synchronized` блок, так как происходит две разные операции, между которыми поток может быть остановлен или в этот момент времени произошло изменение значения из другого потока.

```
synchronized (vo_al) {
    vo_al.set(0, vo_al.get(0) + 1));
}
```

> Есть ли в принципе смысл, в многопоточном программировании помечать коллекции словом volatile?

Есть, если в каком-то потоке происходит изменение ссылки.

```
volatile ArrayList <Integer> vo_al = new ArrayList<>();

// в одном из потоков
vo_al = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: Да спасибо, уже загуглил. Практически принято. Ссылками на АИ можете дополнить? Oracle, cайты, вики - на ваше усмотрение. Чтобы зашедшие сюда смогли быть уверены в корректности вашего ответа.

Comment: В ответе есть одна неточность, которая как минимум вводит в заблуждение. Речь об утверждении, что в других потоках видны изменение _только_ в `volatile`  переменной. Это не так. Правильно так: при чтении `volatile` переменной в другом потоке будут видны все результаты операций записи сделанные до записи в `volatile` в оригинальном потоке.